# PreparedStatement Close Issue for MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am unable to locate where the following exception occurs.  I have closed the `PreparedStatement` after the loop finishes, but still it gives me the error while calling the `sendBill` method:

Exception text:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
 No operations allowed after statement closed.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:461)
```

Relevant code:

```
void executeBills()
{
    try{
        PreparedStatement preStatementUpdate = null;
        PreparedStatement preStatementInsert = null;

        if(preStatementUpdate==null || preStatementUpdate.isClosed())
                    preStatementUpdate = con.prepareStatement(sqlUpdatequery);

        if(preStatementInsert==null || preStatementInsert.isClosed())
            preStatementInsert = con.prepareStatement(sqlInsertQuery);


        for(int i=0;i<countrylist.size();i++)
        {
            country=countrylist.get(i);

            //Error shown on this line no. 
            sendBill(country,preStatementUpdate,preStatementInsert)

        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //closing PreparedStatement
        preStatementUpdate.close();
        preStatementInsert.close();
    }

}

void sendBill(String country, PreparedStatement _1, PreparedStatement _2)
{

    //Code of PreparedStatement setting String parameter.. 

    //...error shown on this line no. 
     //getCreditAmount returns int,  so String.valueOf is used
     _1.setString(1,String.valueOf(country.getCreditAmount()));   

    _1.executeUpdate() ;  
    _2.executeUpdate();


     //No closing preparedStatement Here

}
```

Comment: pls add the stack trace

Comment: @Stephan  added! Previously I also used to get...   java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement is closed.

Comment: it doesn't help very much since i hoped to see at what line the exception is thrown ..

Comment: also in `sendBill` method instead of `preStatementUpdate.executeUpdate() ;` it should be `_1.executeUpdate() ;` and further more `executeUpdate()` throws a SqlException which is not handled in your code

Comment: A few things 1) Very bad practice to just catch exception. 2) You havent posted how you are getting the db connection. Are you able to perform any other operations using your db related code ? I am assuming country has a size and some value

Comment: @Stephan  sorry.. typing mistake..  the method has try..catch block.. I am finding the line no. where it's giving error..

Comment: @happybuddha.. Yess. the code is very long so I kept just some blocks where error is occurring.  Yes. country has size and value , it's an object

Comment: @Stephan  Updated with the line no. shown error in

Comment: so the exception occurs when `setString()` is called?

Comment: @Stephan  might be.. but it says Statement Close Exception..  how can that be? as i have called it after the loop is finished!

Comment: are you sure this is the exact code that you are using?

Comment: @Stephan not the exact code.. but same code with different variables..

Comment: can you post the exact code? because i do not see any issue in this one.